# Getting LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT to ignore a large background image

Tags: android, layout, background, resize

I'm trying to make a LinearLayout that has height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT.

I am receiving an arbitrarily sized bitmap from a server to set as the background image for the LinearLayout.

How do I set the background image of the LinearLayout without resizing the view if the received bitmap is larger than the contents of the linear layout?

It would be nice if the background image could maintain its aspect ratio, and scale to match the width of the screen.

I tried overriding onMeasure as a temporary solution, but that just wound up biting me.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what you mean... you said that you don't want to resize the View, but your LinearLayout's height is WRAP_CONTENT, which means that it will increase as you add Views in the layout. Anyway, you could resize your bitmap so that it will have the resolution that you want (and you could do it without changing its original aspect ratio).

Answer (score 2):

how about using an imageView inside your layout , which also has its adjustViewBounds set to true in order to keep aspect ratio?